Collapsed new cinder block wall
Family member is building a cinder block building. The “mortar”( probably not using the right term) between the blocks appeared a sandy brown color between the blocks,instead of the grayish mortar mix I see on other properties being built. House is currently without roof, just block walls. After a rather hard rainfall, the eastern section of walls collapsed. Could it be that the blocks had too much sand? Is it safe to continue building or should all the walls come down and rebuilt from scratch?

Ask the family member what mix they are using.  All mixes have directions on how to mix it up including the amount of water.  How the blocks are laid is important also.  If one wall collapsed, good bet the other walls are not much better.

It needs to be all torn down and rebuilt with the proper ratios of sand to mortar. For hollow block it can be Type S or Type N.
The ratio is one 70-75 pound bag of mortar, also known as masonry cement, not the ready to mix stuff, although it works too, just expensive to do a whole foundarton or house with, and 18 to 20 shovels of sand. Using a regular round point shovel as your measuring device. The sand needs to be a fine sand, classified as masonry sand. There are coarser types of sand out there, they should not be used. They have their place, but not here.
